# Styling based on hex color codes within table?

Tags: carto, cartocss

I have a table of polygons named 'testtable'.  Within it is a column 'color', which has hex codes.

I want to style the polygons based on the hexcode values.

Is this possible?

I was trying something like this, but it's obviously not working..

```
# testtable{
  polygon-fill: {color};
}
```

Comment: This link is essentially the same thing I'm looking for... I fear it might not be implemented yet.

[link](https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/issues/1809)

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't work with the current system. Buuuut, there is a pretty complex workaround. Take a look at the CartoCSS attached lower down in this example,

http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/5579335

Basically, it encodes a logical statement for 200+ named colors in my column to create a hex.